# How do i display the posts by people who are in the friend list of the user in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two tables called 'posts' and 'friends'. I want to display the 
my code-

```
        $yyss = mysql_query("select * from friends where friend_id='$emaild' or user_id='$emaild'");
    $rp = mysql_num_rows($yyss);
    $fk = mysql_query("select * from friends where friend_id='$emaild' or user_id='$emaild' limit 3");
    while($nr = mysql_fetch_assoc($fk)){
    $frid=$nr['user_id'];
    $ffr = $nr['friend_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts where id='$frid' or id='$ffr' order by unid desc");
}
```

How do I display the posts that are posted by the user's friend without displaying them again and again?

Comment: please clarify your code and your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $friends = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend1 = '$my_uid'"); 
 while($friend = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends)){
     $f[] = $friend['friend2']; 
 }

 $posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id IN
 (".implode(",", $f).")");
```

Comment: This code doesn't work for me....it says `Array` instead of the friend's name when I tried echoing the $posts query.

Comment: all the names have to be within single quotes in the `$posts` query. How do I do that?